# Set maximum allowed replication lag for RDS postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to set up a read replica of a `postgresql` RDS.

However, I want to limit the maximum allowed replication lag.

Is there such an option available on the `postgresql` parameter group configuration?

I could not find anything related in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html).

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the allowed lag is exceeded?

Comment: Kill all running queries so that the replica catches up

Comment: Perhaps `max_standby_streaming_delay` could be what I am [looking](https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/max_standby_streaming_delay/) for but I am not quite sure.

Comment: Yes, that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I think killing queries will be less effective than you think; in my experience streaming lags are only solved via more hardware. You can get the lag from CloudWatch, using the metric [ReplicaLag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-cloudwatch.html#rds-metrics), but like all CloudWatch metrics it will be delayed.